# WPF Radgridview disable context menu if row column header clicked

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgridview

I need to disable a context menu if there are no rows for a radgridview.  Currently if there are no rows, I can right-click anywhere on the grid and the context menu will display.

I tried the code below but get a NullReferenceException trying to set the visibility whether or not the count is zero.

```
            dgChosenItems.DataContext = theLines.allLines

            If theLines.allLines.Count = 0 Then
                dgChosenItems.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            Else
                dgChosenItems.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
            End If
```

Thanks for any help or advice.

Edits:
Here's a snippet of the xaml.  Is there something more I need to add?

```
            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dgChosenItems" FontSize="16" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" ColumnWidth="*" Margin="0,478,10,0" >
            <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu >
                <telerik:RadContextMenu Background="LightGray" Opened="dgChosenItemsContextMenu_Opened"  >
                    <telerik:RadContextMenu.Items>
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem x:Name="menuAdd" Header="Add Mod" Click="AddMod" >
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and check to see what `dgChosenItems` is or `dgChosenItems.ContextMenu` is? I would say that `dgChosenItems.ContextMenu` is nothing or null.

Comment: Yes, ContextMenu is nothing.  How do I set it to what it needs to be?

Comment: You have to assign one to it, evidently you have not and hence the error. Here was a quick find that will help you http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcontextmenu/how-to/use-radcontextmenu-with-radgridview

Comment: See my Edits, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the context menu a name and set it to visible or invisible based on the count of rows in the grid.  So far, it gives the needed functionality.  If there's a better way, please advise.

```
    Private Sub dgChosenItems_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles dgChosenItems.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown

         Dim theLines As New allOrderDetailLines

         If theLines.allLines.Count = 0 Then
             mnuChosenItems.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
         Else
             mnuChosenItems.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
         End If
```